# how to convert Microsoft Map LocationRect to Edges

Tags: bing-maps

Microsoft.Map.getBounds() returns LocationRect object, which it self consist of center,width, height.
i want to find left-top and bottom-right edges to query my database to brings all points in that area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LocationRect class includes a GetNorthwest() and GetSoutheast() functions. You can check the reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427621.aspx)